# Augment predictions from many models in the original dataset

Tags: r, purrr, broom

I want to run many models with all possible combinations of x and ys. I created the following code to do that.

```
library(tidyverse)

y <- names(mtcars)

xs <- map(y, ~setdiff(names(mtcars), .x)) %>% 
  map(~paste0(.x, collapse = "+")) %>%
  unlist()

ys <- names(mtcars)

models <- tibble(ys, xs) %>%
  mutate(Formula = paste0(ys, " ~ ", xs)) %>% 
  mutate(model = map(Formula, ~glm(as.formula(.x), data = mtcars)))
```

Now, I want to get all the predictions from all these models in the original dataset, here mtcars. How can I do that? Is there a way to use augment from broom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` and `augment` similar to the way you fit `glm` to each row.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

y <- names(mtcars)

xs <- map(y, ~setdiff(names(mtcars), .x)) %>% 
  map(~paste0(.x, collapse = "+")) %>%
  unlist()

ys <- names(mtcars)

models <- tibble(ys, xs) %>%
  mutate(Formula = paste0(ys, " ~ ", xs)) %>% 
  mutate(model = map(Formula, ~glm(as.formula(.x), data = mtcars))) %>%
  mutate(Pred = map(model, augment))
```

The prediction is in the `.fitted` column in each dataframe from the `Pred` list.

```
models2 <- models %>%
  select(Formula, Pred) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(`.rownames`, names(mtcars), Formula, `.fitted`) %>%
  spread(Formula, `.fitted`)
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks! How can I pull those predictions from the Pred list then so that every prediction stays in the main mtcars dataset?

Comment: Almost! I actually want the predictions in columns eg. mpg_pred, cyl_pred, ...carb_pred with 32 rows. I guess, tidyr::spread could be leveraged to do that?

Comment: Wow...fantastic! To make the predicted variable names, I made one small change and used it: models2 <- models %>%
  select(ys, pred) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(ys, `.rownames`, names(mtcars), `.fitted`) %>%
  mutate(ys = paste0(ys, "_pred")) %>% 
  spread(ys, `.fitted`)  Can you put this in your answer for the benefit of other users?