# How to run ggpredict() in a loop following multiple regression models?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

The aim is to get the output of the predicted probabilities of several regression models. First i run several regression models using the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
library(ggeffects)

mtcars$cyl=as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

df <-  mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(model1 = tidy(lm(mpg  ~ wt + gear + am , data = .),  conf.int=TRUE)) %>%   
  gather(model_name, model, -cyl) %>%                        ## make it long format
  unnest()
```

I would like to get the predicted probabilities of my predictor weight (`wt`). If i want to run the code manually for each different cylinder (`cyl`), it will look as the following:

```
#Filter by number of cylinders
df=filter(mtcars, cyl==4)
#Save the regression
mod= lm(mpg  ~ wt + gear + am, data = df)
#Run the predictive probabilities
pred <- ggpredict(mod, terms = c("wt"))
```

This will be the code for only the first cylinder `cyl==4`, then we would have to run the same code for the second (`cyl==6`) and the third (`cyl==8`). This is a bit cumbersome. My aim is to automize that as i do for the regression analyses in the first code above. Also, I would like to get these results in the same format as the first code. In other words, they should be in a format that could be plotted afterwards. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Did you see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329741/augment-predictions-from-many-models-in-the-original-dataset) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rerun the models with `ggpredict()` on the inside:

```
df <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(model1 = ggpredict(lm(mpg ~ wt + gear + am, data= .), terms = c("wt"))) %>%
  gather(model_name, model, -cyl) %>% unnest_legacy()
```

You can then plot wt (in the 'x' column) against 'predicted'. Note that you'll get a warning message on these data.